# Unable to post request from android API 23 using HttpUrlConnection.

Tags: android

private class PostDataTOServer extends AsyncTask {

```
    private String path = "http://10.0.2.2/letshare/api/Ride/Test";
    String response = "";
    HashMap<String, String> postDataParams;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        postDataParams=new HashMap<String, String>();
        postDataParams.put("strMessage", "test");
                  try {
            json = HttpurlConnectionParser.makeHttpUrlConnection(path, postDataParams);//new JSONObject(response);
            //Get Values from JSONobject
            System.out.println("success=" + json.get("success"));
            success = json.getInt("success");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        if(success==1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Employee Added successfully..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

public class HttpurlConnectionParser {

```
public  static JSONObject jObj=null;
public  static InputStream is = null;
public  static String json = "";
public  static HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;


public HttpurlConnectionParser()
{
}

public  static JSONObject makeHttpUrlConnection(String urlPath, HashMap<String, String> data)
{
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlPath);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQueryData(data));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        urlConnection.connect();
        boolean isError = urlConnection.getResponseCode() >= 400;
        //The normal input stream doesn't work in error-cases.
        is = isError ? urlConnection.getErrorStream() : urlConnection.getInputStream();
       // is=urlConnection.getInputStream();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line= null;

        while ((line=reader.readLine())!= null)
        {
        sb.append(line+"\n");
        }

        json = sb.toString();
        is.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jObj;
}


public  static String getQueryData(HashMap<String, String> data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Boolean first = true;

    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry:data.entrySet())
    {
        if(first)
        first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(),"UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(),"UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

}

Here is my WEB API simple action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Test(string strMessage)
    {

        return Request.CreateResponse("hello");
    }
```

It always return {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://10.0.2.2/letshare/api/Ride/Test'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Ride' that matches the request."}

Here is my Android post code and WEB API action

Anyone please tell me where i missed something. I just stuck last 2days but unable to call simple web api action.

Comment: Does the post work using curl from the command line or other apps?

Comment: No it always return 404 error with following message
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://10.0.2.2/letshare/api/Ride/Test'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Ride' that matches the request."}